# Looping through a json file and retrieving the values into bash variables

Tags: json, bash, shell, scripting, jq

I have a json file which has the below data

```
{"Item": {"ID": {"S": "4869949"},"no":{"N": "2"}}}
```

I need to retrieve the S value from ID and N value from no and put them into a query as parameters.. the query looks like this:

```
query --table-name validation \
  --key-condition-expression "ID = :v1 AND no = :v2" \
  --expression-attribute-values '{":v1": {"S": "${ID}"},":v2": {"N": "${no}"}}' \
  --region us-east-1
```

I have tried using jq but couldn't figure out how to read a json file and retrieve the values as parameters. This is the first time I am using jq. Can someone help with it?

Comment: Please format your question to make it more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basic jq syntax:

```
$ ID=$(cat data.json | jq .Item.ID.S -r)
$ no=$(cat data.json | jq .Item.no.N -r)
$ echo $ID $no
4869949 2
```

I'd suggest you read something like https://shapeshed.com/jq-json/ to get more familiar though.

Comment: Will it work if I have multiple files in the JSON file ? Because I want to pass these parameters on the fly into the dynamo query

Comment: Provide your exact json - the query will need modifying and will depend on the layout

Comment: {
    "Item": {
        "ID": {
            "S": "48699"
        },
        "no": {
            "N": "2"
        }
    }
} {
  "Item": {
    "ID": {
      "S": "38699"
    },
    "no": {
      "N": "5"
    }
  }
}
{
  "ID": {
    "S": "58699"
  },
  "no": {
    "N": "6"
  }
}this is the kind of items the file will have.will have to retrieve the S,N values each time and pass them into the query. similar to a for/while loop in java is that possible ?Can get all the values using this cat check.json | jq -r '.[] | "\(.ID.S)\t\(.no.N)"'  but need to get one value at a time

Answer (score 1):

The following may not be exactly what you're after but does show how you can avoid calling jq more than once, and how the command can partly be constructed by jq.  In other words, assuming the templates for `--key-condition-expression` and `--expression-attribute-values` are fixed, you should be able to adapt the following to your needs:

Assuming a bash or bash-like shell, and that data.json holds:

```
{"Item": {"ID": {"S": "4869949"},"no":{"N": "2"}}}
```

we could write:

```
ID=ID
no=no

< data.json jq --arg ID "$ID" --arg no "$no" -cr '
  .Item
  | .ID.S as $v1
  | .no.N as $v2
  | $v1, $v2, {($v1): {"S": $ID}, ($v2): {"N": $no}}
' | while read -r v1
do    
  read -r v2
  read -r query

  echo query --table-name validation \
  --key-condition-expression "\"ID = $v1 AND no = $v2\"" \
  --expression-attribute-values "'""$query""'" \
  --region us-east-1
done
```

#### jq as a template engine

If the template with :v1 and :v2 in the Q are variable, then you could adapt the above by using jq as a template engine, a topic which is covered in the jq Cookbook:  https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#using-jq-as-a-template-engine